# Safari bug on d3 transition over scaled svg

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I've been working on transitions in d3js over a scaled background svg. However, in Safari (10.0.1) I'm seeing artefacts appearing when the transitions occurs.

The artefacts cut off the background circles in the example (open first fiddle in Safari).

These artefacts remain, unless I force a new rendering (for example, resizing the window).

Chrome and Firefox do not show this problem.

Here is the fiddle for a small example (open in Safari): [fiddle with scaling](https://jsfiddle.net/thijsihatestatistics/7ag8cjxb/)

Code in fiddle with scaling:

```
var N = 200;
var wh = 600;
var r = 20;

var svg = d3.select('body').append("svg").attr('width',wh).attr('height',wh);
var country = svg.append('g');
country.attr("transform", "scale(" + wh +"," + wh +")");

for(var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  var cx = Math.random();
  var cy = Math.random();
  country.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", cx)
    .attr("cy", cy)
    .attr("r", r/wh)
    .style('fill',"#ccc");
}

svg.append('circle')
  .attr("cx", 0)
  .attr("cy", 0)
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr("cx", 0.5*wh)
  .attr("cy", 0.5*wh)
  .attr("r",r*1.5)
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr("cx", 0)
  .attr("cy", 0);
```

When I do not scale the background svg, the artefacts do not show: [fiddle without scaling](https://jsfiddle.net/thijsihatestatistics/rqy2aj5d/)

Code in fiddle without scaling:

```
var N = 200;
var wh = 600;
var r = 20;
var svg = d3.select('body').append("svg").attr('width',wh).attr('height',wh);
var country = svg.append('g');

for(var i = 0; i < N; i++) {
  var cx = Math.random()*wh;
  var cy = Math.random()*wh;
  country.append("circle")
    .attr("cx", cx)
    .attr("cy", cy)
    .attr("r", r)
    .style('fill',"#ccc");
}

svg.append('circle')
  .attr("cx", 0)
  .attr("cy", 0)
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr("cx", 0.5*wh)
  .attr("cy", 0.5*wh)
  .attr("r",r*1.5)
  .transition()
  .duration(500)
  .attr("cx", 0)
  .attr("cy", 0);
```

Has anyone encountered this before? And is there a solution for it?

Comment: report a webkit bug.

Comment: I will do that. but i hoped there was a solution for this problem

Comment: We have encountered this (now). Did you find a solution Thijs?

Comment: Safari is cool with setting attributes 'height' and 'width' without setting a specific unit, like 'px'?